ReactJS function is not getting the latest parameters
I have constructed a singleton class as an external state management solution for my ReactJS app. My issue is that the function parameters inside components do not get updated.
export class ProductSearchStore {
    private static instance: ProductSearchStore;
    searchTerm: string = "";
    subscribers: Set<() => void> = new Set();

    private constructor() {}

    public static getInstance(): ProductSearchStore {
        if (!ProductSearchStore.instance) {
            ProductSearchStore.instance = new ProductSearchStore();
        }
        return ProductSearchStore.instance;
    }

    public subscribe = (cb: () => void): (() => void) => {
        this.subscribers.add(cb);
        return () => {
            this.subscribers.delete(cb);
        };
    };

    public set = (value: Partial<ProductSearchStore>): void => {
        this.searchTerm = value.searchTerm ?? this.searchTerm;
        this.subscribers.forEach((cb) => cb());
    };

    public get = (): string => {
        return this.searchTerm;
    };
}

export function useProductSearchStore(): [string, (term: string) => void] {
    const productSearchStore = useRef<ProductSearchStore>(ProductSearchStore.getInstance());
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<string>("");

    function updateSearchTerm(): void {
        productSearchStore.current.set({ searchTerm: term });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = productSearchStore.current.subscribe(() => {
            setSearchTerm(productSearchStore.current!.get());
        });

        return () => {
            unsubscribe();
        };
    }, []);

    return [searchTerm, updateSearchTerm];
}

Here is the implementation inside a React component:
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useProductSearchStore();

function updateSearchTerm(term: string) {
    console.log("searchTerm", searchTerm);
}

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("searchTerm", searchTerm);

}, [searchTerm]);

The useEffect function outputs the latest searchTerm correctly but the updateSearchTerm function is not it always returns an empty string.
